# Meteor.http.call (call URL API)

Tags: json, meteor, callback, get, meteor-helper

so I'm trying to make a call to a bible verse API in my Meteor application. I made a template with `name="display"`, with a simple `{{checkitout}}` in the template.

Then for the template, I tried to make the call in its corresponding helper. It looks like this (in coffeescript, but Javascript readers should understand as well):

```
@Template.display.helpers
    checkitout:->
        result = Meteor.http.call("GET","http://labs.bible.org/api/passage=john%203:2&type=json")
        console.log(result)
```

The URL is a JSON of a bible verse, but the problem is, the `Meteor.http.call` requires a third argument, a "callback" (because this is in the client folder). I read some documentation + examples and have no idea what it means.

Also, if I call it like this, is result exactly the JSON file, or do I need to fit it within a new hash? And what does a callback mean? Can someone give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

On the client, the callback is required as you said. So this is something you could do to query an API and display the JSON result:

```
Template.Display.helpers
  checkItOut: ->
     Meteor.http.get 'https://graph.facebook.com/facebook', (error, result) ->
       if not error
         console.log result  # display the the open graph result
```

**Note 1**: To use these functions, you need to add the HTTP package to your project with `$ meteor add http`. You can find further information [in the documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#http).

**Note 2**: In your situation, you cannot make an API call client-side due to the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` Policy. So, the solution would be to use a method and make the call server-side.

```
# Client-side
Template.Display.helpers
  checkItOut: ->
    Meteor.call 'getBibleText', (error, result) ->
      if not error
        console.log result


# Server-side (server directory)
Meteor.methods
  'getBibleText': ->
    result = HTTP.get 'http://labs.bible.org/api/?passage=john%203:2&type=xml'
    return result
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. I did add the http package, and I did read the documentation, so thanks for providing me with an example to better understand it. Could you please walk me through the (error, result) thing, and what it does?

Are you declaring a function with "error and result" as inputs? Are the input names set? Like for example, if I declare it as (error, answer) -> console.log answer instead, would it work? What if I named error something else?

Comment: I ran this code, and the app gave me this error:    "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://labs.bible.org/api/?passage=john%203:2&type=xml. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. "

What does it mean? (Sorry I tried the two space to get <br/> but it doesn't work)

Comment: For your first question, yes you could declare parameters to be (error, answer) -> console.log answer, it would work the same way. From the documentation: *When run in asynchronous mode, the callback receives two arguments, error and result. The error argument will contain an Error if the request fails in any way, including a network error, time-out, or an HTTP status code in the 400 or 500 range.*

Comment: **For your second question, try to make the call server-side (put the code in your server directory). You could then use a Method to retrieve the result on the client.** Also, if you want absolutely to run it client-side, [I think you will need to ask them to allow your domain to access their API](https://bible.org/contact?category=Permission) (this will get rid of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`). Anyway, the better solution is to make the call server-side.

Answer (score 1):

As helpers are synchronous and API calls are not, you need to store the call result in a reactive variable and return it from the helper:

```
verse       = "Loading..."
verseLoaded = false
verseDep    = new Deps.Dependency()

Template.Display.checkItOut = ->
  verseDep.depend()
  unless verseLoaded
    verseLoaded = true
    Meteor.http.get "...", (error, result) ->
      verse = "..."
      verseDep.changed()
  verse
```

Comment: So I have no idea what dependencies are, read some documentation, here's my understanding (for this situation):  
  
So you're declaring a variable using dependency to store the API output (which gives me JSON from an outside database) in order to use this output right? So with VerseDep you call a new dependency.   
    
1) What does verseDep.depend() do? Does it say that this function uses the verseDep dependency?  
2) And what does .changed() do?